# Как перевести строку в дату и время python?

Tags: python, дата, время, datetime

Дана строка `'25.01.2020  23:00:00'`, подскажите, пожалуйста, как ее можно перевести в дату и время и прибавить 2 часа? Чтобы на выходе получилась строка `'26.01.2020  01:00:00'`

Comment: Нужно ли учитывать летнее/зимнее время и смену часовых поясов России в 2014-м, когда время сдвигалось на час вперёд-назад?

Comment: нет, уже дали ответ, но спасибо за уделенное время.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime as DT, timedelta

dt_s = '25.01.2020  23:00:00'
dt_fmt = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'

res = (DT.strptime(dt_s, dt_fmt) + timedelta(hours=2)).strftime(dt_fmt)
print(res)
>>> 26.01.2020 01:00:00
```

Comment: Спасибо выручили)